# How to run Google Chrome Beta in fullscreen mode from cli on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-console

I need to execute Google Chrome Beta in fullscreen mode via CLI on Windows 10.
It have to be beta version cause I'm using WebSerialApi from experimental features.

I've tried those flags:

`C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application>chrome.exe  --app "file:///C:/Users/jack/Desktop/MyApp/index.html" --kiosk --fullscreen --start-fullscreen`

Still fires in normal mode.
I have tried those flags separately also.